# Joined-True cuts data to be plotted

Tags: plotting

I have imported data (which are so many numbers and if necessary please see http://pastebin.com/RgWLJmTS) and I plotted them with

```
ListLogPlot[{data},
   Frame -> True,
   Joined -> True}
```

I have this fig
[image]

But when I use

```
ListLogPlot[{data},
   Frame -> True,
   Joined -> False}
```

I have [image]

There is a problem with `Joined` which caused a cut in plot. How can I have joined data in `ListLogPlot` without any being cut.

Comment: Please post `data` somwhere, for example [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your problem with only `ListLogPlot` but addition of `PlotRange -> All` option should solve it:

```
ListLogPlot[data, Frame -> True, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All]
```

> [image: plot]

I can reproduce your problem only using `Show`:

```
Show[ListLogPlot[data, Frame -> True, Joined -> True], PlotRange -> {Automatic, 10^-3}]
```

> [image: plot]

This behavior is not a bug: it is [documented](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange.html) (under the "Details" section) behavior of the default `PlotRange -> Automatic` option:

[image: screenshot]

```
Options[ListLogPlot, PlotRange]
```

> ```
> {PlotRange -> Automatic}
> ```

Comment: I don't see in the docs where points may be dropped even though they fall within the auto generated plot range.

Comment: @george2079 I have added screenshot of the web page with the Documentation statement encircled.

Comment: @george2079 The points are not dropped if they fall withing the auto generated plot range (I mean `PlotRange -> Automatic`).

Comment: I see..the issue is that `ListPlot` has discarded points beyond *its* auto range and then after the fact you set a larger range in `Show`. I guess I'm confused because @Bstates didn't indicate using `Show`, but most likely he did and just didn't include all the code.

Comment: I also was confused by the code given by @Bstates and suspected that there is unknown bug with his particular dataset. But actually there is no bug and the code in the original question is misleading. Should we edit the question to correct the code? I'm not quite sure how we should handle such situations...

Comment: give him some time to clarify and then edit.